# Neo4J LOAD CSV Memory issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've read many blogs/SO questions about the problem with eager queries in neo4j for LOAD CSV - but I'm still getting a hung db with eventual memory issues.

Here is my query

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///follows.csv" AS line
MATCH (u:User {username: line.follows})
MATCH (p:User {username: line.username})
MERGE (p)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u)
```

15GB file. I avoided the WITH and multiple MERGE statements. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: can you give the `EXPLAIN` of the query ?

Comment: Uploaded png now.

Comment: OK there is no issue with your query. SO what memory problem do you have ?

Comment: What is your heap configuration?

Comment: Have you tried using the [neo4j-import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) tool instead?

Comment: @logisima The memory usage slowly creeps to the max heap size (18GB) and hangs forever (no transactions are created in the store after a certain amount of time). The import works for smaller files (1M rows) but fails on larger than 10M

Comment: @MichaelHunger 18GB. I believe it's a eager issue as the 20M file to simply create nodes works fine - it's only on this MATCH/MERGE pattern that it fails